# Entity Framework Core - How to return freshly added object with loaded navigation properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

After adding a new object to the database, I want to return it with populated relationships. Is there any way to achieve this in other way than overwriting my entity with another ef core db call?

```cs
    public async Task<TrackResponse> Handle(CreateTrackCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Track entity = request.ToEntity();
        foreach(string id in request.OrderHeaders)
        {
            OrderHeader dbEntity = await _db.OrderHeaders.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id, cancellationToken)
            ?? throw new ResourceNotFoundException(nameof(OrderHeader), id);
            entity.OrderHeaders.Add(dbEntity);
        }
        _db.Tracks.Add(entity);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        entity = await _db.Tracks.Include(m => m.OrderHeaders).FirstAsync(m => m.Id == entity.Id, cancellationToken);
        TrackResponse response = entity.ToResponse();
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: You can explicitly load the navigation properties.

Comment: Oh, I get it:
_db.Tracks.Entry(entity)
        .Collection(m=>m.OrderHeaders)
        .Load();

Comment: [Explicit Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit)